# How to get all the possible forms x=p(x) of equation f(x)=0

Tags: python, math, sympy

```
x**3-2*x-5=0
```

To the following forms [x = p(x)] where p(x) is  continuously differentiable:

```
x=5/(x**2-2)

x=(2*x+5)**(1/3)

x=(x**3-5)/2
```

Comment: Haven't used sympy for a long time now, but http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html covers simplification and expansion in general terms.

Comment: I've edited your question to a more readable form. Rollback if this is not what you meant.

Comment: Is the idea here that you want to determine the polynomial `p(x)` such that `x = (p(x))**a` satisfies `x**3-2x-5=0` for a given `a`?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq No, i just want x=p(x)

Comment: @[Math stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1791673/430077)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rough solution only..

```
from  sympy import *
import numpy as np
var('x')
expr=sympify('x**3-2*x-5')
p = poly(expr);

p1=factor(p-(p).coeff_monomial(1))
for i in p1.args:
    if (poly(i).is_monomial):
        z=(np.prod([j for j in p1.args if j!=i]))
        p2=(-(p).coeff_monomial(1)/z)**(1/degree(i));
        v=i.coeff(x)
        if p2:print(p2)
        elif v:
                p2=(-z/v)
                print(p2)
for i in (p.all_terms())[:-1]:
    if i[1]:
        p3= ((i[1]*x**i[0][0]-expr)/i[1])**(1/Integer(i[0][0])) ;print(p3);

'''o
5/(x**2 - 2)
(2*x + 5)**(1/3)
x**3/2 - 5/2
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Given an expression, such as `expr = x**3-2*x-5`, assumed to be zero, one can form an equation x = p(x) in many ways. The simplest is to add x to both sides:  `Eq(x, expr + x)`.

This prints as one would expect: `pprint(Eq(x, expr + x))`:

```
     3        
x = x  - x - 5
```

A couple of more interesting rewrites:

Iteration for Newton method: `Eq(x, simplify(x - expr/diff(expr, x)))`

```
       3    
    2⋅x  + 5
x = ────────
       2    
    3⋅x  - 2
```

Isolating the leading term on one side and taking a root:

```
p = poly(expr)
Eq(x, (LM(p) - expr)**(1/degree(p))) 

    3 _________
x = ╲╱ 2⋅x + 5
```